# On-board ST-Link Firmware

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, firmware, stm32f4-discovery, st-link

There is an on-board ST-Link on [STM32F4Discovery](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) [board](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084.pdf) based on STM32F103 MCU. If I have to use this circuit in my design then where could i get the ST-Link firmware for STM32F103 MCU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no officially supported way of doing this. ST does not make the ST-Link firmware available for public use.

Unless you're designing a development board, there's no reason to use an onboard ST-Link anyway. If you want to allow the user to update the firmware on their device, consider implementing a USB bootloader (or using one that's already present on the device, if applicable).

Comment: While building an adapter into anything but a dev board or educational product is odd, comparable function CMSIS-DAP firmware is available as source and binary.  However when implemented in a full speed MCU it is slower for commanded flash operations than an STLINK given buffer size limitations of USB HID in full speed mode. Still it is not uncommon for MBED and Make Code UF2 type boards, especially where the fake mass storage trick is also tried.